# Does Rational Functional tester Support Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2012 integration?

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio

[image]

When i am trying to install RFT. At this moment i am not able to select visual Studio integration. My system already have visual studio 2012 installed on my desktop. The check box for Microsoft Visual Studio .NET integration is also disabled.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is available in IBM's support knowledge base (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21378152)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is dated but are you still looking for this integration ? There is an RFE open on this topic at 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=44398
that you could go vote and influence a change. I would strongly encourage you to do that if there is still the need.